# Optimizing List Multiplications

Tags: list-manipulation

I've got a list manipulation optimization problem. Consider a two-dimensional nxm list `list1`, and a three-dimensional nxmxm list, `list2`. Is there a faster way of taking the following product?

```
Table[list1[[i]].list2[[i]].list1[[i]], {i, 1, length}]
```

I know that Table operators are notoriously slow, and this seems like there might be a built-in list-manipulation operator to accomplish the same thing, or something very similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a straightforward application of `MapThread`:

```
out = MapThread[Dot, {list1, list2, list1}]
```

You can also use `Thread` as in the following, but it displays a `Dot::dotsh` message (which can be silenced with `Quiet`)

```
out = Quiet@Thread[list1.list2.list1];
```

Comment: Seems to be what I want :-)